# Is there a better way to use From and Into for structs that share a common inner field

Tags: rust

I have a number of structs which wrap a `Builder` struct. These wrappers provide specialized behavior over this `Builder`. It should be easy to convert between these wrappers as they are essentially just the `Builder` with specialized methods. I have written some code to illustrate - it seems like a lot of boilerplate for something simple. Is there a better way?

```
struct Builder;

trait ObjectBuilder: Into<Builder> + From<Builder> {
  fn from_other<T: ObjectBuilder>(x: T) -> Self {
     let builder = x.into();
     builder.into()
  }
}

struct OtherBuilder {
   inner: Builder
}

impl From<Builder> for OtherBuilder {
    fn from(x: Builder) -> OtherBuilder {
        OtherBuilder {
            inner: x
        }
    }
}

impl Into<Builder> for OtherBuilder {
    fn into(self) -> Builder {
        self.inner
    }
}

struct OtherOtherBuilder {
   inner: Builder
}

impl From<Builder> for OtherOtherBuilder {
    fn from(x: Builder) -> OtherOtherBuilder {
        OtherOtherBuilder {
            inner: x
        }
    }
}

impl Into<Builder> for OtherOtherBuilder {
    fn into(self) -> Builder {
        self.inner
    }
}

impl ObjectBuilder for OtherBuilder {}
impl ObjectBuilder for OtherOtherBuilder {}

fn main() {
    let x = Builder;
    let y: OtherBuilder = x.into();
    let z: OtherOtherBuilder = ObjectBuilder::from_other(y);
    let y = OtherBuilder::from_other(z);
}
```

[Playground URL](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0f3940205e0cc4f864e224bc423d8553&version=stable&backtrace=0)

[Gist URL](https://gist.github.com/0f3940205e0cc4f864e224bc423d8553)

Comment: You could use the [newtype_derive](https://danielkeep.github.io/rust-custom-derive/doc/newtype_derive/index.html) crate but that only works with tuple structs i.e. `struct OtherBuilder(Builder)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining wrapper structs, you could define extension traits for `Builder` – i.e. traits that are only implemented on `Builder`, which provide additional functions that you can invoke with method call syntax (`builder.func()` instead of `func(builder)`). Then, you can import only the traits that are relevant in the proper scope (be it module scope, function scope, etc.).

One downside to this approach is that if you have multiple traits providing methods with the same name, then calling these methods with method call syntax would be ambiguous (if more than one thread is imported in the relevant scope), as the compiler wouldn't know which trait you're referring to. Sure, you can disambiguate the call by using normal function syntax (`MyBuilderExt::func(builder)`), but that's not pretty. In that case, perhaps the wrappers are a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce repetition in your code by using macros:

```
struct Builder;

trait ObjectBuilder: Into<Builder> + From<Builder> {
  fn from_other<T: ObjectBuilder>(x: T) -> Self {
     let builder = x.into();
     builder.into()
  }
}

macro_rules! builder {
    ($name:ident) => {
        struct $name {
           inner: Builder
        }

        impl From<Builder> for $name {
            fn from(x: Builder) -> $name {
                $name {
                    inner: x
                }
            }
        }

        impl Into<Builder> for $name {
            fn into(self) -> Builder {
                self.inner
            }
        }

        impl ObjectBuilder for $name {}
    }
}

builder!(OtherBuilder);
builder!(OtherOtherBuilder);

fn main() {
    let x = Builder;
    let y: OtherBuilder = x.into();
    let z: OtherOtherBuilder = ObjectBuilder::from_other(y);
    let y = OtherBuilder::from_other(z);
}
```